# Time period in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

A simple question, but some quick Googling did not prove fruitful.

Basically, I have a column called "uniqueID", which is a unique identifier for all the people in my dataset. Most uniqueIDs have multiple records, because there is one record per year that the person stayed at university. What I'd like to do is create a "time period" variable, where first year, t= 1, second year t=2, third year t=3 etc. for each unique ID.

Comment: That seems sensible, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: How does one do such a thing?

Comment: Which part? Do you now know how to add a column? Or is the problem calculating the value (in which case we need to hear about your other data)?

Answer (score 1):

The following is faster IF YOUR SPREADSHEET IS SORTED by your unique id;

=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)

(assumes that above formula is in column B and that data begins on row 2)

and, of course, copied down for all rows as described above.

You will find that in a spreadsheet containing many rows that COUNTIF is very slow since you are looking up through ever-increasing range sizes.